# How to create a new branch that doesn't contain last commit

Tags: git, repository, git-branch

I have a Github repository that contains solution of many exercises 
ex: part1-A then part1-B whereas the part1-B is the same of part1-A with some modification , so when I commit the Part1-B the part1-A  is lost and replaced with part1-B 
so that i create a branch for part1-B but when I commit it it show the part1-A and any commit before creating the new branch . 
My question is 
How can I make the branch for Part1-B alone without any commits happened before creating the branch?

Comment: You need to create Part1-A branch from a clean branch (Ex: master branch), then create Part1-B branch from the same master branch. When you will create the second branch you need to put all your code from 0 and do an initial commit

Comment: @FranDioniz thank you for reply \ but the part1-A is the master branch here

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b <new branch name>
git rebase -i <first commit in the repo>
```

pick the first commit
squash the rest

The resulting branch will have two commits: the very first one in the repo, plus one more, which is the net result of all subsequent commits.

Edited per comment to get the other branch down to just one commit:

```sh
# establish new branch with just one commit in it
git checkout -b part1-B <first commit in the repo>

# ensure an empty directory
rm -rf <every file except .git*>

# copy the entire contents of the other branch here
git checkout part1-A .

# stage everything that was just copied in
git add -A

# amend the one and only commit in this new branch to include
# all the files that were just copied in
git commit --amend -m 'entirety of part1-A in a single commit'
```

You will then have a branch called `part1-B` whose file contents are identical to that of `part1-A`, but squashed down to a single commit.  The branches have no common ancestor.

Comment: thanks @Bill Jetzer  but i don't want the branch to have the first commit in the repo